# Нужно получать активные уведомления на моем смартфоне, и выводить их через текст в моем приложении

Tags: java, android

нужна обратная связь от более опытных java программистов, вот у меня есть java класс, но мне не совсем понятны некоторые кусочки кода:

```
  public class ReceiveNotificationsPlugin extends NotificationListenerService
 {
   Context context;
   public String title;
   public String text;

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();
    context = getApplicationContext();

}

 public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn, final IReceiveNotificationsCallback callback)
   {
    String pack = sbn.getPackageName();
    String ticker ="";
    if(sbn.getNotification().tickerText !=null) 
    {
        ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
    }
    Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
    title = extras.getString("android.title");
   text = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();
    int id1 = extras.getInt(Notification.EXTRA_SMALL_ICON);
    Bitmap id = sbn.getNotification().largeIcon;


    Intent msgrcv = new Intent("Msg");
    msgrcv.putExtra("package", pack);
    msgrcv.putExtra("ticker", ticker);
    msgrcv.putExtra("title", title);
    msgrcv.putExtra("text", text);
    if(id != null) 
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        id.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        msgrcv.putExtra("icon",byteArray);
    }
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(msgrcv);


 }

}
```

мне не совсем ясно, может ли этот код получать все текущие уведомления на моем смартфоне и выводить их с помощью текста, также не совсем ясно, зачем нужны строки типа msgrcv.putExtra("package", pack); и ей подобные...
У меня есть Unity приложение, которому мне нужно передавать содержимое java переменных title и text; Но сейчас вопрос конкретно о java коде, а именно о его работоспособности. Также у меня есть интерфейс, который я использую для связи моего java класса с моим C# кодом:

```
public interface IReceiveNotificationsCallback 
{
    void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn);
}
```

Задаю я этот вопрос потому что при попытке взглянуть на все текущие уведомления на моем смартфоне не выходя из моего приложения, я ничего не вижу... Вот сейчас и пытаюсь понять на чей стороне ошибка - java или C#

Comment: Вторая часть кода (начиная с `Intent msgrcv = new Intent("Msg");`) - это передача полученных данных дальше (другим компонентам приложения) через локальную широковещательную рассылку. Подразумевается, что какая-то из активностей при запуске зарегистрирует ресивер и будет получать через него эти данные. Я такой задачи не делал и наверное мало кто ещё, поэтому я бы вам посоветовал не ждать доброго дядю, а сделать минимальный проект в Андроид студио (без юнитов) и самому потестировать этот код в нём. Довести его до работоспособности, а когда(если) уже получится - прикручивать к юнитам.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш комментарий! я попробую!